# How to query all custom post type + post and page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a problem of query. I want to query all custom post type + post page in wordpress. But this is not working. What have i done wrong i don't know. Please help me anyone.

Check the code bellow:

```
public function my_post_get_all_types_post() {
    $posts_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'post_style' => 'all_types',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $posts = $posts_args;
    $post_list = [];
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $post_list[$post->ID] = $post->post_title;
    }
    return $post_list;
}
```

Output code:

```
$this->add_control( 'blog_any_post',
        [
            'label' => __('Source', 'useful-addons-elementor'),
            'label_block' => false,
            'type' => Controls_Manager::SELECT,
            'multiple' => true,
            'default' => [],
            'options' => $this->UA_post_get_all_types_post(),
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your above functions with follows -

```
public function my_post_get_all_types_post() {
    $posts_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'post_style' => 'all_types',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => -1,
    );
    $posts = get_posts($posts_args);
    $post_list = [];
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $post_list[$post->ID] = $post->post_title;
    }
    return $post_list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but post type not showing. Just showing all post's title... :(

Comment: Can you tell that what you want to show as in drop-down values?

Comment: this is working i have changed this line ** $post_list[$post->post_type] = $post->post_type; ** thanks for your answer..:)